# Display Text and Details in C# WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

Just need to know how can I display text and details like shown in the image.

Which control type with which mode is it?

[image]

Comment: Looks like a ListView control with some custom drawing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) with tile display. See [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s8z85th0%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for more info. The tutorial describes which properties to set to obtain a display like below.

[image]

From the tutorial:

> You can adjust the size of the tiles by setting the TileSize property, and the number of text lines displayed in the tile by adjusting the Columns collection.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.